# How to count and limit record in a single query in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am searching for records in a table as follows:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM my_table WHERE Name LIKE '%prashant%' LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Now, I am adding LIMIT to maintain my paging. But when user searches for word 'prashant' then total records I have is 124 for 'prashant'. But as the limit applied to the query so it only fetches 10 records in my PHP script and when I am count the mysql variable in PHP code it returns total records found is 10.

So basically I want to count and Limit using a single query, by making some modification in the above query, I want the total count (124) of records. I don't want to run a separate count(*) query for just counting the total result found by the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  Id, Name
FROM my_table
WHERE
  Name LIKE '%prashant%'
LIMIT 0, 10;

# Find total rows
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: MySQL never fails to amaze in the ad-hocery department.

Comment: "MySQL never fails to amaze in the ad-hocery department." - I am not getting this, please explain...

Comment: It's a not very valuable extension to support paging on web pages, and it's pretty obvious reading the MySQL docs that it wasn't really well thought out before it was added. And it has poor performance. In short, it's a hack.

Answer (score 11):

MySQL supports doing this using [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) as mentioned by Ionut. However, it turns out that [in many cases](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) it's actually faster to do it the old fashioned way using two statements, where one of them is a regular `count()`. This does however require that the counting can be done using an index scan, which won't be the case for this very query, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: Just an update to the link: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: No problem ;) Though I found a better solution (that I posted below).

Answer (score 7):

This is for others with the same need (considering it's been 3 years from the time of this question).

I had a similar issue and I didn't want to create 2 queries. So what I did was to create an additional column for the total number and moved the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses at the end:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `name`
    FROM `my_table`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%prashant%'
) res,
(SELECT /*CEIL(FOUND_ROWS()/10) AS 'pages',*/ FOUND_ROWS() AS 'total') tot
LIMIT 0, 10
```

So the result is something like

```
| id  |      name      | total |
+-----+----------------+-------+
|  1  | Jason Prashant |  124  |
|  2  | Bob Prashant   |  124  |
|  3  | Sam Prashant   |  124  |
|  4  | etc. prashant  |  124  |
```

and I think this solution has no disadvantage in timing because it fetches the result only once, and then uses the **already calculated** row count for the additional column.

Answer (score 2):

In case of huge tables and selecting multiple fields (not just Id, Name as in your example) i would recommend to use 2 queries. Selecting count(0) first with all those WHERE clauses and only then build the pagination, selecting data etc. 
It will work really faster on some popular eCommerce website, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()

1. there are the bugs reported
   here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18454
   and here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19553
2. while on small tables BENCHMARK is dependent more on other things and the resulting time your SELECT will take will be roughly the same as COUNT(0) - SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS still puts restraints on LIMIT and ORDER BY database optimizations so if you depend on them **don't use** SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
3. on large tables the BENCHMARK difference becomes huge where a COUNT(0) might take 0.003 sec the same SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS might now take 20 sec

By all metrices COUNT(0) is the superior choice

COUNT(0) SYNTAX:

```
(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tableNames WHERE condition) AS alias
// alias is optional but needed if you need to use the result later
```

So your total query would look like this

```
(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%prashant%') AS countResults;

SELECT Id, Name FROM my_table WHERE Name LIKE '%prashant%' LIMIT 0, 10;
```

And then just call countResults whereever you need it elsewhere...

Another advantage of using COUNT(0) is you can use it for searching both the same table as here or you can use it to search a different table...

So for instance if each person found also has 3, 2, 1, 5 diffenrent jobs respectively... you could just add a

```
(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM my_jobs_table WHERE name = name_row_in_jobs_table) AS jobs
```

inside your original SELECT like this

```
SELECT Id, Name (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM my_jobs_table WHERE name = name_row_in_jobs_table) AS jobs FROM my_table WHERE Name LIKE '%prashant%' LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Giving you:

```
--------------------
| id | Name | jobs |
--------------------
| 1  | Alice| 3    |
--------------------
| 2  | John | 2    |
--------------------
| 3  | Bob  | 1    |
--------------------
| 4  | Jill | 5    |
--------------------
```

So when showing name[3] (ie. Bob) you could also show that Bob has 1 job by calling jobs[3]...