# How to return record count in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query with a limit and an offset. For example:

```
select * from tbl
limit 10 offset 100;
```

How to keep track of the count of the records, without running a second query like:

```
select count(*) from tbl;
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802373/how-to-count-and-limit-record-in-a-single-query-in-mysql) answers my question, but I need it for PostgreSQL. Any ideas?

Comment: I need something with one query only, because my query is very slow (about 1 second) and I cannot run it twice due to performance issues (my query runs a full-text-search on a very large table).

Comment: It's also meaningless unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Дамян Станчев: So it's a performance issue and there's really no reason why you can't use a second, count query?

Comment: There is - to select the count(*) I must re-fetch the full-text-search reuslts again along with the other limitations and the query is quite slow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution and I want to share it. What I do is - I create a temp table from my real table with the filters applied, then I select from the temp table with a limit and offset (no limitations, so the performance is good), then select count(*) from the temp table (again no filters), then the other stuff I need and last - I drop the temp table.

```
select * into tmp_tbl from tbl where [limitations];
select * from tmp_tbl offset 10 limit 10;
select count(*) from tmp_tbl;
select other_stuff from tmp_tbl;
drop table tmp_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but from the section titled `Obtaining the Result Status` in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html) you can use the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command to determine the effect of a command.

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS number_of_rows = ROW_COUNT;
```

From the documentation:

> This command allows retrieval of system status indicators. Each item
>   is a key word identifying a state value to be assigned to the
>   specified variable (which should be of the right data type to receive
>   it). The currently available status items are ROW_COUNT, the number of
>   rows processed by the last SQL command sent down to the SQL engine,
>   and RESULT_OID, the OID of the last row inserted by the most recent
>   SQL command. Note that RESULT_OID is only useful after an INSERT
>   command into a table containing OIDs.

Answer (score -3):

Depends if you need it from the psql CLI or if you're accessing the database from something like an HTTP server. I am using postgres from my Node server with node-postgres. The result set is returned as an array called 'rows' on the result object so I can just do

```
console.log(results.rows.length)
```

To get the row count.