# How can I count total results returned from MySQL query with a limit?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I am using the following query to grab results from a MySQL database:

```
$query =  $this->db->query("
    SELECT * FROM results r 
    INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
    INNER JOIN tags t on r.id = t.result_id 
    WHERE c.name in ('$purpose', '$prop_type', '$loan_type')
    $tag_string
    AND ( r.scope = 'all' OR r.scope = '$subdomain' )
    GROUP BY r.id
    HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) = 3
    ORDER BY r.usefulness DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset
");
```

The returned results can potentially be 500+

How can I count the total amount of rows this query would return if there were no limit so I can display it to the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" is what you want:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: I actually tried that and got the following error... 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' at line 10

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM results r INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id INNER JOIN tags t on r.id = t.result_id WHERE c.name in ('purchase', 'single_family', 'usda') AND ( r.scope = 'all' OR r.scope = 'redflagwiki' ) GROUP BY r.id HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) = 3 ORDER BY r.usefulness DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

Comment: This process still needs to be done over 2 queries: If you are typing that at a prompt, make sure you add a semi-colon after "OFFSET 0". In PHP, do your initial query just adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, and then do another query as "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();"

Comment: In newer versions of mysql these functions are being deprecated as of 8.0.17, so probably not a great solution anymore :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

They recommend using the following instead:
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100;

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, just use `select count(*) from ...` instead of `select * from ...`

If you like to do it all within the same query, you got your answer here:

[How to count and limit record in a single query in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802373/how-to-count-and-limit-record-in-a-single-query-in-mysql)

An additional `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` would be the answer.

Comment: He's asking for the count without the limit.

Comment: Of course it would still need to be a second query using `select count(*)`, so `FOUND_ROWS()` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Running in to an issue with this... I think it's to do with the HAVING COUNT line of my query, when I try to count using select count(*) the count is always 3... any ideas?