# Effective use of pagination and MySQL queries

Tags: mysql

At the moment I run two MySQL queries to handle my pagination...

Query 1 selects all rows from a table so I know how many pages I need to list.

Query 2 selects the rows for the current page (e.g: rows 0 to 19 (LIMIT 0, 19) for page 1, rows 20-39 for page two etc etc).

It seems like a waste of two duplicate queries with the only difference being the LIMIT part.

What would be a better way to do this?

Should I use PHP to filter the results after one query has been run?

**Edit:** Should I run one query and use something like array_slice() to only list the rows I want?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802373/how-to-count-and-limit-record-in-a-single-query-in-mysql

Comment: Interesting, the answers in that post suggest to use two queries rather than that supposed "hack"... Hmmm...

Comment: Are you not using count() on q1? Why?

Comment: Hi, the 2 queries method is widely used, and fast. BUT you should not use the same query and remove only the limit! To count the rows use the least columns as possible, ideal only one key field, for instance a PK field (select count(id) as c from tablename).

Comment: Good call @JorgeFerreira that's what I've been doing to date :)

Comment: @Ben Sinclair: I think you don't know what you require and what you accepted. You have accepted your problem itself.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk or maybe I realised what I was doing in the first place was the best way anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best & fastest way is to use 2 MYSQL queries for pagination (as you are already using), to avoid over headache you must simplify the query used to find out the total number of rows by selecting only one column (say the primary key) that's enough.
`SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE condition1>1 AND condition2>2` 
for paginating such a query you may use these two queries 
`SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE condition1>1 AND condition2>2 LIMIT 0,20
SELECT id FROM sampletable WHERE condition1>1 AND condition2>2`

Comment: That is what OP is saying. He don't want headache of firing 2 queries. He wants total rows count and limited result in single query. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first SELECT would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT clause.

Note that this puts additional strain on the database, because it has to find out the size of the full result set every time. Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` only when you need it.

Comment: found_rows() is a terrible idea especially because SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS will fetch all the rows even though you only want the first 20 rows. So basically your fetching x number of records while you really want 20 or so records. if x is in millions and your query has many joins, you will keep your user waiting for a long time!